# $ command not recognised in terminal

Tags: git, terminal

I am trying to install git for the first time so I used the command '$ brew install git' as it suggests on the git documentation. But when entering the command my terminal says 'zsh: command not found: $'

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

$ is a symbol commonly used to signify that it is to be entered in the terminal / command line.

It shouldn't be pasted into the command line however.
Example: `$ git push origin main` is telling you to type "git push origin main" into your terminal.